# Trigger TinyMce File uload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, tinymce

I am using TinYMce WYSIWYG editor, It is working fine. I am using OpenSource product without MCFileManager, instead files/images are uploaded via TinyBrowser which is included.
Now I need to trigger this pop-up window where I can browse files to upload from element.
Is there any way to do that via upload files?

P.S Maybe there is a way to get that MCFileManager for free or some kind of license?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the available licences and prices [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_filemanager.php), you won't get it for free (at least not leagaly).

I never used TinyBrowser, but i am sure you could write your own Tinymce plugin and include your own button to trigger the TinyBrowser.

Comment: Thanks! Well thats my question "how to trigger it?" :)

Comment: use your firebug to have a closer look at the button from where you usually call it. there should be an onclikc handlöer revealing what code to put into your tinymce plugin to trigger it

Comment: Well, I already tried that but the JS that comes from element wont work.